# How to reset focus for a Xaml SwapChainBackgroundPanel

Tags: xaml, focus, windows-runtime

I have a page which is actually SwapChainBackgroundPanel that I use to render to with SharpDx (essentially a C# DirectX wrapper). For my input, I handle the Pointer* and Key* events of the panel. The problem is that the panel also has a Button (back button) up in the corner and for some reason that button is getting default focus. So when I press the space bar, it is invoking the button's click event.

To prevent this from happening the user has to click on the background (the panel) to put the focus back on it. The problem is that I cannot find a way to programmatically move the focus back to the panel and off of the button. Only the button has any function to set the focus, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move focus to another invisible button:

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        x:Name="b"
        Content="click"
        Click="B_OnClick" />
    <Button
        x:Name="b2"
        Opacity="0.005" />
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
    private async void B_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        b.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        b2.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
```

My other answer doesn't seem to work here, but I'll keep it since it might work in the future and I believe it should work on Windows Phone.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't pass the key events to the main panel. But atleast I don't accidently hit the back button though...

Comment: Catch the key events on CoreWindow instead - `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown`

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling

```
button.IsEnabled = false;
button.IsEnabled = true;
```

to lose focus from the button.

Comment: you can try to put a delay in between `await Task.Delay(100)`

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work either...
Let me try another answer.